# how to concatenate the long labels which are in multiple lines

Tags: r, loops

I have a data can be created by codes:

```
structure(list(tx = c("Form: Enrollment", "    Field Name   Data Type    Field Label  Units Pre-Filled Include Field", 
" 1 SITENUM       $3           Site:                         SITENUM", 
" 2 SCRNO         $4           Subject No.:                  SCRNO", 
" 3 SUBJID        $8           Subject ID:                   SUBJID", 
"Form: Date of Visit", "    Field Name    Data Type   Field Label   Units Pre-Filled Include Field", 
" 1 DOVDT          dd MMM      Date of Visit                  DOVDT", 
"                  yyyy        (DD MMM", "                              YYYY):", 
" 2 DOVAE          $1          Was subject                    DOVAE", 
"                              assessed for", "                              adverse", 
"                              events?", " 4 DOVCM          $1          Was subject                    DOVCM", 
"                              assessed for", "                              concomitant", 
"                              medications?", " 6 DOVCP          $1          Was subject                    DOVCP", 
"                              assessed for", "                              concomitant", 
"                              procedures?", "Form: Date of Visit_1", 
"    Field Name    Data Type   Field Label   Units Pre-Filled Include Field", 
" 1 DOVDT          dd MMM      Date of Visit                  DOVDT", 
"                  yyyy        (DD MMM", "                              YYYY):", 
"Form: Continuation", "    Field Name   Data Type    Field Label Units Pre-Filled Include Field", 
" 1 CONTYN        $1           Will the                     CONTYN", 
"                              subject", "                              continue to", 
"                              next visit?", "Form: Continuation_1", 
"    Field Name   Data Type    Field Label Units Pre-Filled Include Field", 
" 1 CONTYN        $1           Will the                     CONTYN"
), page = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(page = 1:5, 
    .rows = list(1:5, 6:22, 23:27, 28:33, 34:36)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

As you can see, form value come from each page's 1st row, and then we need to somehow split inputs into 5 variables that were defined by row 2.
The very tricky part is how to concatenate the long labels which are in multiple lines.
Might need to use loop. Feel like it is very complex task.

Any creative way to solve this?
Many thanks.

Comment: "Form: Date of Visit", "    Field Name    Data Type   Field Label   Units Pre-Filled Include Field" 
It is very hard to split above text. Using a single space results, you separate such column names as "Field" and "Name". Using more than one spaces, you obtain "Units Pre-Filled Include Field" as a whole. It is not possible unless it is used a specific separator. 
a = structure(list(tx = c("Form: Enrollment", ...
a_sp = apply(a, 1, function(r){strsplit(r[1], "[ ]{2,}")[[1]]})

Answer (score 1):

Your columns in the data field are not very well define.  Here is a solution that should get you started.
See the comments in the script for an explanation of the steps.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#split the initial table by page ID
textlist <-split(text, text$page)

x<-lapply(textlist, function(page) {
   #extract form name
   Form <- gsub("Form: ", "", page$tx[1])
   #define column ID
   dfnames <- c("ID", "Field Name", "Data Type", "Field Label",    "Include Field")
   print(Form)
   
   #create temp file and read the 3 - last line as a fixed width file
   ff <- tempfile()
   cat(file = ff, page$tx[(3:length(page$tx))], sep = "\n")
   #column widths may need tweaking
   df <- read.fwf(ff, widths=c(2, 13, 12, 30, 9))
   
   #fill the first column to identify which to merge together
   df <-fill(df, V1, .direction="down")
   
   #merge the rows togeter for the 3 and 4 column
   df <-df  %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(
      V2=trimws(first(V2)), 
      V3=paste(trimws(V3), collapse = " "), 
      V4=paste(trimws(V4), collapse = " "), 
      V5=trimws(first(V5)))
   #rename the columns and bind the form name on
   names(df) <- dfnames
   ddf<-cbind(Form=Form, df)
   ddf
})

#create the final answer
dplyr::bind_rows(x)
```

**Output**

```
              Form ID Field Name    Data Type                                       Field Label Include Field
1       Enrollment  1    SITENUM           $3                                             Site:        SITENU
2       Enrollment  2      SCRNO           $4                                      Subject No.:         SCRNO
3       Enrollment  3     SUBJID           $8                                       Subject ID:        SUBJID
4    Date of Visit  1      DOVDT dd MMM yyyy                       Date of Visit (DD MMM YYYY):         DOVDT
5    Date of Visit  2      DOVAE        $1             Was subject assessed for adverse events?         DOVAE
6    Date of Visit  4      DOVCM        $1    Was subject assessed for concomitant medications?         DOVCM
7    Date of Visit  6      DOVCP        $1     Was subject assessed for concomitant procedures?         DOVCP
8  Date of Visit_1  1      DOVDT dd MMM yyyy                       Date of Visit (DD MMM YYYY):         DOVDT
9     Continuation  1     CONTYN        $1             Will the subject continue to next visit?        CONTYN
10  Continuation_1  1     CONTYN           $1                                          Will the        CONTYN
```

Comment: Could you teach me how to get such output. I ran your codes and got x as list of 5.

Comment: Yes, x is a list of 5 dataframes and the bind_rows function will combine them into a single data frame.

Comment: may i know how to find the working column widths ? I tried the codes on the complete data set, and got the error message `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 5 did not have 5 elements". how should i adjust it?

Comment: The above code doesn’t have any error checking thus the errors you are seeing in a larger dataset. I determined the columns widths but estimating the widths of values in each column and then tweaked them by some trial and error.  You may need to add a try and catch routine to prevent these errors from stopping everything.